# Table data always empty when printing into pdf - fpdf

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I have separate code, one that allows user to select id from the database and the other one to display all its value when submit button is pressed. :
    (eto.php)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "auth";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "auth");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT id_no from employee ORDER BY id_no asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<form action="http://localhost/pdf2/id.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
Print By ID Number:
   <select name="id" id="id" onchange="changeSelect(this.value)">
   <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { ?>

 <option value="<?php   
 echo"<input type=hidden name=id size=30  id=id value=$row[id_no] required>"; 
 ?>" >  
       <?php echo($row['id_no']); ?>

   </option> 
   <?php }  ?> 

</select>
<input type="submit" name="submitID" value="Print"/>
</form>


<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function changeSelect(value)
{
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value
}
</script>
```

(id.php --fpdf form that prints table values) :

```
<?php
require('mysql_table.php');
if(isset($_POST['submitID']))
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
class PDF extends PDF_MySQL_Table
{
function Header()
{
//Title
$this->SetFont('Arial','',18);
$this->Cell(0,6,'Type of Leave',0,1,'C');
$this->Ln(10);
//Ensure table header is output
parent::Header();
}
}
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('auth');
$pdf=new PDF();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->AddCol('leave_id',20,'','C');
$pdf->AddCol('fullname',40,'Fullname');
$pdf->AddCol('type_of_leave',40,'Type of Leave','R');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
        'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
        'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
        'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table("select leave_id, fullname, type_of_leave from application where             id_no='$_POST[id]'",$prop);
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Once I pressed the submit button it successfully prints the pdf but data of the table is always empty. Mysql database is not empty and is working properly. What's the problem with this?

Comment: Your option values are invalid html -> `<option value="<?php   
 echo"<input type=hidden name=id size=30  id=id value=$row[id_no] required>";?>"`. Instead of an `id`, your values are `<inputs>` so when you try to do `WHERE id_no='$_POST[id]` you get an invalid id.

Comment: how can i fixed this? please...

Comment: Try simplifying to `<option value="<?php echo $row[id_no];?>"`